# How can I create a wrapper class of two model classes in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm working on an app where I have two very similar model classes. I want to use both of these classes in one view controller, which layout is based on properties from the model classes. The problem is that I currently have a lot of if statements to check which class it is.

Example:

```
- (UIView *)setUpViewForObject:(id)object
{

    // Check if it is a Post or Event object
    Post *post;
    Event *event;
    if ([object class] == [Event class]) {
        event = (id)object;
    } else if ([object class] == [Post class]) {
        post = (id)object;
    }

    if (post) {
        // Do stuff
        // ie:
        self.customUiView.textField.text = post.text;
    } else if (event) {
        // Do similar stuff
        // ie:
        self.customUiView.textField.text = event.text; 
    }
}
```

This solution seems pretty redundant, and I do it in a couple of places. I therefore wonder if it is possible to create a wrapper class of two NSManagedObject classes. I use CoreData and have generated the models from xCode so I wouldn't use all these if statements.

Something like:

```
@interface News : NSManagedObject
[...]
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;
[...]

@interface Event : NSManagedObject
[...]
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;
[...]
```

Is it possible to create a wrapper class of these two NSManagedObject classes, maybe with enums. I also would like the objects to be updatable, deletable etc. Was thinking that I maybe could use Enum or something similar to create an abstract class, but I don't know how a class like that would look, work and be used.

Any suggestions if this is possible and in that case how a wrapper class like this would look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if ([object class] == [Event class])` is dangerous, use `[object isKindOfClass:[Event class]]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data supports the concept of an abstract superclass. So you define that with one property, say "tag", that differentiates the two classes. Then News and Event both have that class as their superclass. This is a very common type of solution used with Core Data.

Comment: Thanks, should the abstract superclass have all the common properties or only one?

Comment: You can add all the common properties you want. We used this technique just like you read in the textbooks - an "Animal" base class, then specialized subclasses etc. Works great! Then you can always test an object "isKindOfClass:" with the abstract superclass before setting a property etc.

Comment: Cool, how will this work with the code sample I posted in my original question, with the if statements. Can I do as @bogdan-andresyuk writes in his answer, or will this work differently? My models in now cleaner which is great! But it would be even better if I wouldn't need all these if statements too. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - but add a new field to the root like "tag" and make it an integer, then uses #defines to set it to different numbers for different classes. Then you can test on that "tag" value which may be easier to type than testing on the class. In the end its the same logical test, its just what I propose is (IMHO) easier to type.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do in this way:

```
//in NewsEventRootObject.h
@interface NewsEventRootObject:NSManagedObject //root object for these two classes

[...]

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *text; //similar fields in here

-(void) getSomeValue;

//in News.h
@interface News : NewsEventRootObject

[...]

-(void) getNews;

//in Event.h
@interface Event : NewsEventRootObject

[...]

-(void) getEvent;

//in your "handler".m

- (UIView *)setUpViewForObject:(NewsEventRootObject *) object
{ 
    //you can access similar fields and methods without if/else statements
    self.customUiView.textField.text = object.text;

    SomeValue *someValue=[object getSomeValue];

    //but for class-specific you should make a check
    if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(getEvent)]) {

    }

    if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(getNews)]) {

    }

}
```

And really, never check classes via == , use isKindOfClass statement

Comment: This isn't ideal. It's preserving the 'switch statement/if logic as polymorphism' anti-pattern that often means polymorphism would be a better solution.

Comment: if models are very similar (as stated in subject) and Anders won`t use class-specific methods and variables this is an ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks, was difficult to select who to give the right answer. Your suggestion was also very close to the one I ended up with.